# How to draw a x axis line without grid line in mpchart or remove grid line first line on x axis and y axis on android mpchart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I need to set X-axis and Y-axis in one color with different width and draw grid lines in different color and width. When I added the code below, I saw the x and y-axis lines overlapped with the grid line, which looks like the attached screenshot.

linechart.legend.isEnabled = true

xAxis.isEnabled = true

xAxis.axisLineWidth = 2f

xAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.5f

leftAxis.enabled = true

leftAxis.axisLineWidth = 2f

leftAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.5f

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM0y0.png)